# can't locate language.pm in centos

Tags: perl, centos, perl-module

The below is the error occuring after running ./checksetup.pl

```
Can't locate Locale/Language.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib/x86_64-linux-thread-multi lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5)
```

I've tried using command

```
sudo yum install liblocale-codes-perl
```

but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

In the Centos7 & 8 VMs I have, the package is named 'perl-Locale-Codes'.  This should work for you:

```
sudo yum install perl-Locale-Codes
```

Answer (score 2):

`liblocale-codes-perl` is a Debian-world name for a pre-packaged CPAN distribution. The Red Hat world uses "perl-" followed by the CPAN distribution's name.

So it's `perl-Locale-Codes`.